# Why can't we offer a bounty of less than 100 rep on PMSE?

Tags: support, bounty

On Stack Overflow, a bounty can be offered for as little as 50 reputation points. As a relatively low-rep user, I'm not all that excited about offering 100+ bounties on other questions as a means of generating interest in questions that I think are meritorious, but what I have very little stake in personally.

Why are we prevented from offering 50-point bounties? Can that be fixed? If not, why not?

Comment: @jmort253 On SO, I have the option a 50-point bounty on my own questions, so I think think that's it. This was the post I thought could benefit from more eyeballs and additional answers. Since it isn't my question, I'm not sure how your previous comment would apply, even it were true. http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/6230/4271

Answer (score 1):

From [Clever bounty reputation hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826):

> - If you are placing a bounty on a question you answered, your minimum spend is 100
> - If you are placing a repeat bounty on a question, your minimum spend doubles till it reaches 500

Since you've already answered this question, your minimum spend is 100. However, you could use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management) to try to convince another to leave a bounty.

Or, as you've done, leaving a comment is a good option as well to see if someone else is interested in bringing more attention to this question.

As an example, I posted a bounty on [How do you calculate schedule compression ratio?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/how-do-you-calculate-schedule-compression-ratio). While I had the option to post a 50 rep bounty, I went ahead and posted it for 100.